# How do I change the color of the text when it is in the photo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

There is a block with a photo and a specific title. When scrolling, this text changes its position (transform: translate3d). It is necessary to change the color of the symbols when they are on the photo.

Perhaps someone has come across such a situation and can help in this? I have attached a photo for a better understanding of the task

[image]

Comment: almost the same as : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254727/change-text-color-if-background-image-is-not-white-html/51254788#51254788

Answer (score 2):

If you want a pure CSS solution, you can use [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).  Note what browsers it is available in though.

It will decide how content from one element should blend with the content of the element's direct parent.

```css
:root {
  --main-color: white;
  --secondary-color: black;
}

#app {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, var(--main-color), var(--main-color) 30px, var(--secondary-color) 30px, var(--secondary-color) 60px);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.blend {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="blend">Hello world, how are you?</div>
</div>
```