# How to easily invert text color based on the background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm really new to JavaScript and such but I think that's what I've got to revert too. I have this navbar from bootstrap:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color:mix-blend-mode: difference;font-weight: bold">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="logo.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#about">About ATCN<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#download">Download<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

and what I'd like to happen is whenever the text is over a white background, the text color would invert.

I've seen multiple posts about this but none of them are using bootstrap, or they are insanely complicated JavaScript scripts. Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: If you can, it's easiest for others to read your question if you include the code inline instead of as a link.

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254727/change-text-color-if-background-image-is-not-white-html/51254788#51254788

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the class .navbar-fixed-top in styles.css on line (1)

```
background-color: #0000004d;
```

The entire class should look like this:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #0000004d;
}
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that

Comment: @GrantMeder You can use this css to invert the color on hover or so, but if you want it to specifically change colors based on background, you might need to use a canvas element or some way to detect background color and see if the element is in position to change colors. Can you give me more details of what content you will have and what colors need to change?

Comment: Sure, if it would be better you can check out the repo here: https://github.com/virtualflying/ATCNotification/tree/development . If not, just let me know and I can upload the website on a test server to show what I'm trying to do

Comment: Perfect I downloaded the template and I see what you mean, to clarify, when I scroll onto the white background it gets hard to see the menu items correct?

Comment: Okay we can go about this two ways, I really want to help you out here. If I go the long way, I would need to create a Javascript script that will change the color if the window height reaches that white area, but remember that this is static and you would need to change it later if you ever change your html mark up. Another way is I can add a faded transparent black background over the top menu when you scroll down a bit. Which route do you want to take?

Comment: I would personally go with the added background color, I just did it on my end and it looks great, this way your users can tell the menu is fixed and scrolls down with them.

Comment: Could you show an example of the second route? The white background DIV is going to be based on percentages, would that affect the way the first route works?

Comment: How is this? https://image.ibb.co/if3ktd/header_color1.png Ignore that white space on top its my google chrome, I cropped it out with paint haha.

Comment: That looks awesome, it would definitely help me out!!

Comment: Alright I will change my reply above with the css information

Comment: Hi. Is enough a function for reverse color when scroll occurred and your element to be placed between desired background element?

Comment: @Hassan No there is not, you need to calculate the window scroll position with the element, if they are overlapping you then apply a css color change to the element desired.

Comment: @Hassan Your english is fine, being multilingual is difficult I can tell your first hand. Keep it up 

Comment: Thanks a lot @GrandIQ.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry; my free time is very short.

please test this:

```
<body style="position: relative">
<div style="position: absolute; top:320px; left: 0; height:150px; width:100%; background-color:#000" id="dseiredcolorfulelem"></div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; height:4000px; width:1px"></div>
<div data-menu style="color: #000; display: block; position: fixed; top:0; left: 0" id="mnu">
    <span style="display: inline-block; padding:0px 50px;">Hello World!!</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var mnu = document.getElementById("mnu"),
        dce = document.getElementById("dseiredcolorfulelem"),
        mC = mnu.style.color;
    window.onscroll = function () {
        if ((dce.offsetTop - window.scrollY <= mnu.offsetTop + mnu.clientHeight) && (dce.offsetTop + dce.clientHeight - window.scrollY > mnu.offsetTop)) {
            var CL = dce.style.backgroundColor, C = [];
            if (CL.indexOf("rgb") == 0) {
                CL = CL.replace(/\d+/g, function (N) { var r = (N * 1).toString(16); C.push(r.length == 2 ? r : "0" + r); });
                CL = "#" + C.join("");
            } else if (CL.length == 4) CL = CL.replace(/./g, function (a) { return a + a }).substr(1);
            mnu.style.color = CL.replace(/[a-z0-9]{2}/gi, function (p) { var rt = (255 - parseInt(p, 16)).toString(16); return rt.length == 2 ? rt : "0" + rt; });
        } else mnu.style.color = mC;
    };
</script>
```

this is a full example but without paying attention to bootstrap or your code. you can test it in fiddlers or in a empty html file (with html tags).

i hope this helps.

**i modify fiddle and code. please test now.**

[Test Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51q7twyf/11/)

Comment: why down vote?? it is a simple example. elem with `id='mnu'` is your menu. elem with `id='dseiredcolorfulelem'` is element with different color. another elem is for create scroll for body.