# Change text color where the background image moves behind

Tags: html, css, reactjs, framer-motion

The background planet moves in a circular area and changes the text color to orange if the image moves behind.

```
<div>
   <div className={styles.content}>
     <div className={styles.content__title}>
          <h1>
            Explore Your own planet <br /> In{" "}
            <span>our New </span>
            metaverse
         </h1>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.content__description}>
         <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
          dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
         </p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div>
     <Planet />
  </div>
</div>
```

Planet component:

```
const mouseX = useMotionValue(0);
const mouseY = useMotionValue(0);

const handleMouseMove = (e: React.MouseEvent<SVGCircleElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    animate(mouseX, e.clientX - rect.left - rect.width / 2);
    animate(mouseY, e.clientY - rect.top - rect.height / 2);
}

<div className="circle">
            <motion.svg
                width="526"
                height="526"
                viewBox="0 0 526 526"
                fill="none"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
                ...
                <motion.circle
                    cx="263"
                    cy="263"
                    r="263"
                    fill="transparent"
                    onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
                    onMouseEnter={handleMouseMove}
                    onMouseLeave={(e) => {
                        animate(mouseX, 0);
                        animate(mouseY, 0);
                    }}
                    className="circle_detector"
                />
            </motion.svg>
            <motion.div
                className="image"
                style={{
                    translateX: mouseX,
                    translateY: mouseY,
                    transition: "all 3s linear",
                }}
            />
</div>
```

And  background image style:

```
.image {
        position: absolute;
        width: 320px;
        height: 322px;
        top: calc(526px / 2 - 322px / 2);
        left: calc(526px / 2 - 320px / 2);
        background-image: url("../src/widgets/planet/assets/planet.webp");
        background-position: center;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

[Image what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrlXU.png)
The text should change color as the planet moves. To move planet i use framer-motion library. Also video for better understanding:
[video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-H1NCPhcBJXslt4KjpIm8uli5he15QsH/view?usp=sharing)
Is it even possible to do this?
I tried this [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254727/change-text-color-if-background-image-is-not-white) but nothing changed

**UPDATE**

When I try the blend mode, I get something like this: [blend-mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq0Br.png)
Can I change this bluish color to a specific color?

**UPDATE**

Here is a link to the website so you can see what I mean
[Site](https://planet-metaverse.netlify.app)

Comment: Do you have more code?

Comment: You are clearly using some kind of library for "className". You can add it in your tags.

Comment: We're going to need the `background-image` and all code necessary for a [example].

Comment: @Lyokolux the OP does not use a library but a JS-Framework (React). There is no reason to add it as a tag because this question is not React-specific. Tags are not to be used for techs that you use but with relevance to the question!

Comment: @ninadepina added some code

Comment: @Lyokolux Yes i use react but i think it doesn't change anything because it is about html css but i add tag

Comment: It sounds as you're going to need svg filters which gives you much more control https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Filter_effects

Comment: While I agree this doesn’t look like a problem involving react, you have given us react code. Could you instead give us the compiled code I.e. the relevant CSS, JS and HTML, preferably as a runnable snippet. It’s particularly important that we understand what is in the image and what isn’t, given the rings are having no effect on the text in your picture. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added a link to the site for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mix-blend-mode: multiply` to give you something like you are looking for. I've put a layer over the top of the image with `mix-blend mode` which colors the image and the text have a play about with it. There are a [lot of modes you can use](https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/), it's worth experimenting with them.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #111;
  color:white;
  position:relative;
}

.text {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight:bold;
  position: absolute;
  left:3rem;
  top: 2rem;
  z-index:2;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.image::after {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  inset: 0;
  background: darkorange;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='text'>
  Lorem Ipsum yadda yadda
  </div>
  <div class='image'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/58/200/300'>
  </div>
</div>
```

[MDN reference for `mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

**Edited to add background-clip: text example**
I've created and SVG that's the same size as the container and made it white with a circle of the planet's radius in orange. If you position the SVG over  the parent image and use background-clip: text you can make the text appear like you asked.

See below

```css
body {
  background-color: #171719
}

.text {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
  font-size: 120px;
  
  /* make the div the same size as the parent container */
  height: 640px;
  
  /*We've created an SVG and encoded it (see here https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/ for a tool to do that) The SVG is a whie background with an orange circle that we position to overlay on top of the planet image*/  
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='1280' height='644'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='1280' height='644' fill='white' /%3E%3Cellipse cx='960' cy='322' rx='320' ry='322' fill='orange' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  
  /*Make the background appear under the text*/
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}

.image-holder {
  position: relative;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 640px;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  
  /* push the image 640px across so it appears under the text svg */
  left: 640px;
}

.text {
  /* just position the text where we want */
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  place-items:center;
  inset: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class='image-holder'>
  <img src='https://i.ibb.co/QPdRCgN/planet-1fef4106.webp'>
  <div class='text'>
    <div>Explore Your own Planet</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you just want the text to change colour then you'd need to create an image with the various colours you want (white and orange in your case) and use background-clip: text; on the text div. Like this https://youtu.be/oR7fp2xAvpM

Comment: Added a link to the site for clarity

Comment: Added updated example with your planet on it.

Comment: wow it works great!, can i use encoded svg as inline style to dynamically change its position?

Comment: I don't think an inline svg would work as it needs to be set as a background image for the text to clip it.